# Excel export configuration in spring mvc

Tags: spring, excel, model-view-controller, configuration, export

I have a requirement to export data to excel using spring mvc when we click on export button.
i have used AbstractExcelView for exporting excel sheet in spring mvc.
Followed the process mentioned in this link
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-export-data-to-excel-file-via-abstractexcelview/

The problem i am facing is with the configurations.
can u explaing how to configure from jsp to controller and then controller to view class which exports data to excel.

Answer (score 1):

The controller returns the name of the view and the raw data.

```
return new ModelAndView("ExcelRevenueSummary","revenueData",revenueData);
```

Then the view is responsible for rendering/creating the excel document.

```
 public class ExcelRevenueReportView extends AbstractExcelView{

    @Override
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map model, HSSFWorkbook workbook,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {...}
 }
```

To "register" the excel render view there is no so much to do for registering, except creating the excel view bean.

```
<bean id="ExcelRevenueSummary"
    class="com.mkyong.common.view.ExcelRevenueReportView">
</bean>
```

Btw: there is no jsp involved.

---

p.s. I hope [this tutorial](http://javapapers.com/spring/excel-export-in-spring-mvc/) explain it a bit better

Comment: From controller i was not able to redirect to ExcelRevenueReportView class.actually in my configuration file i am using InternalResourceViewResolver which is stopping to redirect to class.

Comment: <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
  <property name="location">
   <value>/WEB-INF/spring-excel-views.xml</value>
  </property>
    <property name="order" value="0" />
 </bean>

Comment: <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="requestContext" />
  <property name="viewClass"><value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles.TilesJstlView</value></property>
    <property name="order" value="1" />
 </bean>

Comment: "From controller i was not able to redirect to ExcelRevenueReportView class." -- This is NO Redirect! this is the View that should render the Model!!

Comment: now i am not able to get the export popup and even there are no errors shown.can any one help on this?

Comment: @user2335437: do you mean the file save / open dialog by the term "export popup"?